# How to solve an error in reading a merged cell value from an excel file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

I have this code to read every cell in an excel file.

```
Do Until objRange.Cells(intRow, 1).value.Equals("小　計")
```

`intRow` increments every time but when the cell points at a row that is merged, say for example, row 3, 4 and 5 are merged - when it points at 3, it executes but when it points at 4, it returns an error - `System.NullReferenceException`

***How do I solve that error so when it cause an error, it will simply increment and move to the next row?*** I tried `On Error Resume Next` but it seems like it did not move to next `intRow`. It still cause an error but this time, it's logical since when it cause an error, it resumes next row so the intRow did not increment but the value seems to be at the incremented intRow position. That's what I've understood. ***Can anyone also explain how exactly this caused logical error?***

Below is my latest code that cause the logical error

```
           On Error Resume Next
            Do Until objRange.Cells(intRow, 1).value.Equals("小　計") 'causes an error
                If objRange.Cells(intRow, 1).Value.Equals("I") Then
                    Do Until objRange.Cells(intRow + 1, 1).Value.Equals("II")
                        If Not objRange.Cells(intRow + 1, 2).Font.Size.Equals("16") Then
                            intBunruiType += 1
                            arrBunruiType(intBunruiType) = "I"
                        End If
                        intRow += 1
                    Loop
                ElseIf objRange.Cells(intRow, 1).value.Equals("II") Then
                    Do Until objRange.Cells(intRow + 1, 1).value.Equals("III")
                        If Not objRange.Cells(intRow + 1, 2).Font.Size.Equals("16") Then
                            intBunruiType += 1
                            arrBunruiType(intBunruiType) = "I"
                        End If
                        intRow += 1
                    Loop
                End If
                intRow += 1
            Loop
```

The program goes this way. The cell values in first column looks like this:

```
I
-
-
II
-
-
-
-
-
III
-
-
IV
```

the `-` represents blank. So when the cell value after `I` is blank, I retrieve I and when the cell value is `II`, I retrieve nothing but cell value after `II` and before `III`, I'll be retrieving `II` and so on... providing that the next column in `I, II, III and IV` does not have the font size `16`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you did `On Error Resume Next`, you were still going to have the problem because `intRow` needs to get incremented so you can get to the next row. You could do something like this:

```
On Error GoTo HandleError
```

Then at the bottom of your sub/function you could put something like this to increment `intRow` and then go back to the line that caused the error:

```
HandleError:
intRow += 1
Resume
```

Another way to handle this would be to check if the cell object is nothing. My guess is that the error is caused by trying to access the `.Value` property of the `objRange.Cells(intRow, 1)` object. You can't get a property from an object if the object doesn't exist. If this is the case, check to see if the object even exists before checking the value. If it doesn't, then just increment `intRow`. You can check to see if the object exists with something like this:

```
If objRange.Cells(intRow, 1) = Nothing Then

End If
```